# get the value of an input type using getElementByClassName in a looped BScard

Tags: javascript, html

this is my looped BScard code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php

        $sqlb = "select * from products where category = 'appetizer' && status ='active'";
        $resultb = $conn->query($sqlb);
        while($rowb = $resultb->fetch_assoc()){
            $id=$rowb['id'];
            $names=$rowb['names'];
            $price=$rowb['price'];
            $image=$rowb['image'];
            $qty=$rowb['qty'];
            $description=$rowb['description'];
            ?>
        <div class="col-sm col-md-6 col-lg-3 ftco-animate btn-cart" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
            <div id="counter" style="display:none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
            <div class="room">
                <span class="image d-none"><?php echo $rowb['image']; ?></span>
                <a href="/products<?php echo $rowb['image']; ?>" class="non-insta image-popup img d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url(../<?php echo $rowb['image']; ?>);"></a>
                <div class="text p-3 text-center">
                    <div class="btn_cart">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-md rotate" id="add">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus icon-spin"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h3 class="mb-3"> <span class="names"><?php echo $rowb['names']; ?></span></h3>
                    <p><span class="price mr-2">₱<?php echo $rowb['price']; ?>.00</span></p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $rowb['qty']; ?>" class="item_qty">
                    </p>
                    <ul class="list">
                        <li><span><?php echo $rowb['description']; ?></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

and this is my script for getting the value of input type text with class="item_qty"

```
var item_qty = document.getElementsByClassName("item_qty")[0];
```

when I was using get elementById it worked just fine because there is only one data, but since I will be using a looped Bootstrap card I figured that I should use getElementsByClassName but it won't/ cant get the data typed by the user.

```
var item_qty = document.getElementById("item_qty").value;
```

what I want to get/ my expected result is; to be able to get the value that the user types. For example,the looped card would get 3 results and we would now have 3 cards with 3 different input text. when the user types "15" on the first input text and clicked the button, I want to be able to get the "15" when the button is clicked.

I can already get the other values of the card, such as item_name and description. the only one left is the quantity which is in input text.

I already tried using getElementByID(id).value; to get the user's input and it worked fine with only one card. but when there are multiple cards with the same id, the data gets all tangled up. how can I achieve my expected result? Is there something wrong with my javascript(getElementByClassName("item_qty")[0];)?

This is my javascipt for fetching the information of the card.

```
window.cart = [];
$('button#add').click(function()
    {
        console.log('this');
        var id = $(this).closest('div.btn-cart').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        console.log(window.cart.includes(id));
console.log($('div#' + id + ' span.names').text());
console.log($('div#' + id + ' span.price').text());
console.log($('div#' + id + ' span.image').text());
console.log($('div#' + id + ' span.qty').text());

var item_name = $('div#' + id + ' span.names').text();
var item_price = $('div#' + id + ' span.price').text();
var item_pic = $('div#' + id + ' span.image').text();

var qty = document.getElementsByClassName('item_qty')
for (i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) {
    // from here you can check the attribute of the input if it was checked, or look for other class name or attribute.
    // console.log(qty[i].checked)
    console.log(qty[i].value);
}

var data = {
    values: {
        temp_id: window.session.temp_id,
        temp_name: window.session.temp_name,
        temp_number: window.session.temp_number,
        item_name: item_name,
        item_price: parseInt(item_price.replace('₱', '')),
        item_quantity: qty,
        item_total: parseInt(item_price.replace('₱', '')) * 1,
        item_pic: item_pic,
        item_id: id
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: "../api/ajax/addToCart.php",
    type: "post",
    data: data
})
.done(function(response){
    console.log(JSON.parse(response));
    getCart();
});


});
```

Comment: There are going to be multiple `"item_qty"` elements. You used index `0` to get one of the elements but that is only the first element on the page. If you put a value in some other element you would need to get the appropriate element using the correct index

Comment: yes, that's it. each input text would have a different value, what I want to get is the value of a particularly clicked card. how can I go about with this?

Comment: Anywhere on the card or on a particular element in your card (like your `<button>`)?

Comment: I think I may have not explained well the problem, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You need to get the actual numbers of the element you want to get the value then loop around them and access their index to get the attribute you want.

```
var qty = document.getElementsByClassName('qty')
for (i = 0; i < qty.length; i++) {
    // from here you can check the attribute of the input if it was checked, or look for other class name or attribute.
    // console.log(qty[i].checked)
    console.log(qty[i].value);
}
```

Comment: it returned an error >Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: @reveberces I believe the error was caused by another script. Can you post more of your javascript codes?